# SCE - Custom Data Feeds

Tags: wpf, windows-client

I am using the syndicated client experience (SCE) SDK. Has anyone had success with creating custom datafeeds for this? I want to be able to host the masterfeed and other feeds at a URL instead of compiling as embedded resources like the example. For instance, the client application would gather its feeds from `http://somesite/masterfeed.xml`.

I believe this can be done, but I keep getting an AccessViolation exception during the debugging of the SCE client.

Answer (score 0):

The application just happened to be writing to a bad memory space.